# How to provide pipes in services in Angular 17 with no NgModule

Tags: javascript, angular, angular17

I am trying to use `titleCasePipe` in  my angular service, I don't have NgModule and using the new `ApplicationConfig` way.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NameGeneratorService {
  // private titleCasePipe = inject(TitleCasePipe)
  constructor(private titleCasePipe: TitleCasePipe) { }
```

I tied both ways for injection ^^

I keep getting  `NullInjectorError: No provider for _TitleCasePipe!` error.

I tried this, still same error

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    importProvidersFrom(TitleCasePipe),
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the pipe to the providers :

```
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    TitleCasePipe,
  ]
```

But honnestly, this is a bad practice.
Pipes are only meant to be used in templates.

If you want to inject such feature, it should be trough a service.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the pipeTitleCase in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/aio/content/examples/testing/src/app/shared/title-case.pipe.ts) you see that you can create a function:

```
export function titleCase(input:any)
{
 return !input || input.length === 0
      ? ''
      : input.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => txt[0].toUpperCase() + 
                                         txt.slice(1).toLowerCase());
}
```

And use it instead of pipe

NOTE: for others pipes like decimalPipe, datePipe, etc, you have the functions formatNumber, formatDate... and it's not necessary import the pipe else the function from `@angular/common`

Comment: Yes, I know I can copy paste that code, but then I need to writing unit tests for this as it's part of my codebase, while using the pipe it self we can mock it